# How to duplicate and add more characters to a string row in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Having a table that storage customer names, I need to duplicate those records and add a character at the end at the same time. For example

I have:

```
CNAME
customer1
customer2
customer3
```

I would like to return:

```
CNAME
customer1
customer1*
customer1#
customer2
customer2*
customer2#
customer3
customer3*
customer3#
```

Could someone please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can union your results together:

```
select
  cname
from
  table1
union all
select
  cname + '*'
from
  table1 
union all
select
  cname + '#'
from
  table1 
order by cname
```

You can see it working in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f540e/4)

Comment: If I have another column named company what I should do is add a , and put the column name after. Like name + '*', company?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a number-table and this query:

```
with c as
(
    select c.*, rn=row_number()over(order by cname)
    from customers c
)
select cname = cname + case n % 3
                when 1 then ''
                when 2 then '*'
                when 0 then '#' END
from numbers n join c
on n between 1 and 3
order by rn
```

Result:

```
customer1
customer1*
customer1#
customer2
customer2*
customer2#
customer3
customer3*
customer3#
```

How to create a number table: http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Comment: Its always a pleasure to be shown up by you Tim. +1

Answer (score 0):

to concatenate strings, example :

```
select u.login || ' ' || u.password from user u
```

output : user 1234

edit : your question is more complex . i thought it was just for concatenating strings.